# Google Spreadsheet infinte range in both ways

Tags: google-sheets, range, aggregate-functions

So if I want to add every number in column B below B26 I can use this:

```
=SUM(B26:B)
```

If I want to add every number below B26, C26, D26 I can use this:

```
=SUM(B26:D)
```

But what can I use if I want to add every number below and next to B26? What I mean is something like:

```
=SUM(B26:infinte)
=SUM(B26:last column containing data)
```

What I want is to make my own Spreadsheet which automatically calculates ANOVA. If I copy data with X rows and Y rows starting from B26 it should work no matter how many rows and how many columns it has. Adding up infinite rows is solved by `SUM(B26:B)` but how do I add all the columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the whole column from that point and the whole row form that point you can do it like this

```
SUM(B26:B, C26:26)
```

To get the whole area below and right next to it you can do the following

```
=ArrayFormula(SUM(OFFSET(B26,,, MAX(ROW(B26:B)), MAX(COLUMN(B26:26)))))
```

Comment: Sorry, my wording wasnt correct I think.

What I want is to SUM all numbers below B26 and below C26 and D26 and so on until the last column which contains data

Comment: Thanks! The arrayformula is just what I needed!

Comment: Something is not working. The value depends on where I put the formula. 

For example if i have data starting from D5 and my formula is in A1 and I add values below D5 it works fine, but if I add values to the right it doesnt count them.
If I put the formula in A2 and add values 1 cell to the right, it works but not if i add values 2 cell to the right. If I put the formula in A3 it counts them too.

Any ideas?

Comment: Ah, when reducing the formula I didn't check for that, sorry if you the column and row references it should work. I edited the answer accordingly

Comment: Thanks, now it's perfect=)